# Proxy Pass in Nginx based on mobile browser/web browser

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Desktop Website is running on port 8080. Mobile website is running on port 8081. I want to route to respective ports based on accessing from mobile or desktop. Trying to use nginx for this.

Tried something like this :

```
      set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

      if ($http_user_agent ~* "|android|ip(ad|hone|od)|kindle") {
          set $mobile_rewrite perform;
      }

      location / {
        if($mobile_rewrite = perform){
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }

        if($mobile_rewrite = do_not_perform){
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
      }
```

But the above one is not working. Getting error

```
 unknown directive "if($mobile_rewrite=perform)"
```

Comment: please provide what behavior you want & what behavior you are getting with this config.

Comment: You need a **space** between `if` and the `(`.